# Is it bad code to have internal functions for namespaces

Tags: c++

Say I have a namespace Util, which contains some basic functions. But in that namespace I need the functionality of a library to do my work, however I don't want the header file to know about it so I end up making an anonymous namespace with the functionality that I need but don't want exposed. Is there a better way to do this ?

As an example:

```
# Util.h  
namespace Util{  int Add();  }

# Util.cpp
namespace Util{
 namespace {
  funkyInt Add_internal(int x, int y);
  int convert(funkyInt x);
 }

 int Add(int x, int y){
  return convert(Add_internal(x,y))
 }

 funkyInt Add_internal(int x, int y){
 //DOSomething
 }
}
```

Comment: that's pretty much exactly what anonymous namespaces are for. Why do you think there might be a problem with this approach?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I am worried somewhere along the lines I would have to face some overhead that I didn't forsee

Comment: Careful, the namespace needs to be reopened, or you aren't really defining the same static function https://wandbox.org/permlink/jqy55qRzsLNPYrhM

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly fine.

Whether the anonymous namespace is in your namespace or the global one is taste and ease.

- Taste, because the code may be exactly identical
- Ease because if you reuse other function of your non anonymous namespace, you don't have to prefix or use the namespace.